# CommportIdentifier in android

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

We are trying to establish an flow Control from android device to Bluetooth Thermal Printer for that we need to understand the xon and xoff signal sent by printer. We are stuck at getportIdentifier("COM1") its giving exception . Iguess the com1 for bluetooth device is uuid but its not helping. Any help so that we could trace the port for android device.

Regards,
Sebs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the JavaComm interface: this does not exist on Android at all, so you will not be able to use that particular semantics. If this is a Bluetooth serial device you will need to specify the device's Bluetooth MAC address and use the RFCOMM UUID, as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29).